# Using Amazon managed Prometheus to get EC2 metrics data in Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prometheus, managed

How can I get 100 EC2 instances metrics in different regions and account in Amazon managed Prometheus in AWS.. i should get all the metrics disk cpu memory in Grafana.please share me the steps it will be helpful

Not yet tried please guide